# Dynamically Specify Install4J Downloadable Component URL

Tags: java, install4j

I am creating an installer, though Install4J, which contains several large optional components. As such, I would like to make these components downloadable, so that they do not bloat the size of the installer.

I am clear on how to do this (by marking the components as downloadable, and specifying that the data files are downloadable in the media files) so long as I know the "HTTP download URL" to specify in the Media Wizard at compile time.

However, I would like the user to be able to specify the download URL at install time, for example so that they could host the components internally. I am not seeing a way to specify the download URL at install time in the Install4J documentation. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I would guess that the download URL is stored as a compiler variable, and than accessed at install time, but Im not sure what this variable would be called, or if it would be advisable to change it at install time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use installer variables in the download URL on the "Data files" step of the media wizard, like this:

```
${installer:myDownloadUrl}
```

and set the myDownloadUrl installer variable at runtime, for example by calling

```
context.setVariable("myDownloadUrl", ...);
```

in a "Run script" actiom.